# RecyclerView: doing computation work on background with RxJava

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, rx-java

**Context**

I'm trying to improve the performance on an **Adapter** that I have. The thing is that every time that I update this adapter I need to re sort and do some operations with the list of items that this adapter handles. It's an adapter that shows a list of **buildings** but the adapter is also divided in **sections**. For example one section shows the **Recently available** buildings, which are those that got available less than a week ago. **Last month** buildings. And so on.

**Issue**

The adapter works perfectly, but due to all this re sorting of the items and so, I can see that is messing with the UI thread. The SwipeRefreshLayout's ProgressBar looks kinda clunky.

What I want to do is move all the heavy work to a background thread and then, once the re sorting is done, call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

**What I tried so far**

So, this is how my `BuildingAdapter` class looks like:

```
class BuildingAdapter: BaseBuildingAdapter() {
    ...
    fun updateBuildingList(newItems: List<Building>) {
        queueAdapterUdpate {
            // Do all the heavy work here. Update the new items against the already existing collection
            // Make sure that all the buildings are on the right section, etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Now let's take a look at my `BaseBuildingAdapter` class and that `queueAdapterUdpate` function.

```
class BaseBuildingAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {
    ...
    private val subjectQueue = PublishSubject.create<Any>().toSerialized()

    init {
        subjectQueue.apply {
            observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            subscribe {
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }

    fun queueAdapterUdpate(actions: () -> Unit) {
        val observable = Observable.fromCallable(actions)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .replay().autoConnect()
        observable.subscribe(subjectQueue)
    }
}
```

So, this is my first time playing around with Subjects even though I've been using RxJava for a long time. The thing is that in order to **properly update** my adapter, the changes that I perform through the `updateBuildingList(List<Building>)` function must be **sequential**, that's why the `subjectQueue` property is called queue, because I want it to behave like a queue.

The only issue with this is that isn't working the second time that I call the `updateBuildingList(List<Building>)` function. First time works perfectly, but then I try to fetch the second page of my list and it doesn't do anything.

**Question**

Any idea about how to process background work (sequentially) on an Adapter using RxJava?

**Notes**

- I know that using `notifyDataSetChanged()` isn't a performance friendly option, but believe me that I have way too many sections with specific grouping logic.

Comment: Why are you using the queue?  Why doesn't `Shcedulers.computation().scheduleDirect(action)` work? If you need ordering to be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this works only on the first time is that when `queueAdapterUdpate` is called for the first time, it creates the `observable` which will complete after the action. Once this `observable` completes, `subjectQueue` will also complete, and `subjectQueue` won't do anything again after that.

One quick fix is to change the last line:

```
    fun queueAdapterUdpate(actions: () -> Unit) {
        val observable = Observable.fromCallable(actions)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .replay().autoConnect()
        observable.subscribe(subjectQueue::onNext) // this line here
    }
```

Now `subjectQueue` will only get the `onNext` event from the `observable...

However, I have to mention that this is not a good approach to the problem. In fact, I am not sure how the code above is supposed to preserve the order. Currently, the order depends not on the time when the action starts but the time when the action finishes.

If there is a need for a heavy computation, I think it would be better if you can do it outside of the adapter, like in view-model or where you can easily subscribe/unsubscribe based on the ui lifecycle. Then `updateBuildingList` should be called with the result of the computation, not with the pre-computation data.

If it must be done in adapter you could try something like this:

```
class BuildingAdapter: BaseBuildingAdapter() {
    private val subjectQueue = PublishSubject.create<List<Building>>()

    init {
        val disposable = subjectQueue
            . // do computations here using .map, .flatmap, etc.
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                // set data here
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
    }

    fun updateBuildingList(newItems: List<Building>) {
        subjectQueue.onNext(newItems)
    }
}
```

You have other options like single threaded executors or coroutine. Just need to remember that `notifyDataSetChanged()` is called in the Main thread.